# Having the same amount of space with and without multicol when using with titlesec and itemize

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize, titlesec, multicol

I am trying to use `multicol` and `itemize` to spread a list over several columns. I am also using `titlesec` to style my headings. One part of my document uses multicol and the other does not and both have different vertical spacing, which looks odd. I've searched here on stack exchange and all the questions are about reducing the space before the multicol environment, while in my case, I want to increase it so that it is the same as that without multicol. Also, the problem arises only when I use the `titlesec` package. I think I need to set the `multicolsep` value but to what?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section}
\setlength\multicolsep{0pt}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nosep]
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\item Item 4
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\section*{Section}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nosep]
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\item Item 4
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

So, I want the vertical distance between 'Section' and 'Item 1' to be the same in both the cases. The differene in vertical spacing is especially pronounced when I use the `compact` option of `titlesec` like `\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}`. Any ideas on making the spacing equal?

Comment: No idea, but as this type of display already has been treated, just a question: do you want the successive items be displayed first vertically, then horizontally, or in the reverse order? In other words, do you want, e.g. 1, 2 , 3  in the  first column, then 4, 5, 6 in the second and finally 7, 8, 9 in the third — or same thing `per row`?

Comment: I'd prefer them to be 1, 2, 3 in the first column; 4, 5, 6 in the second column; etc. but if the vertical spacing issue can be resolved the other way, I'm okay with that too.

Comment: With your code there's no difference in vertical spacing between the two itemize environments. There must be something else in your code. Just in case, add the `\raggedbottom` directive in your preamble.